# Why is Apache returning Service Temporarily Unavailable on local host?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac, localhost

Ok so I am a bit new at all this.

I was trying to get php and apache2 running on my localhost and I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I keep getting this message when inputting localhost into chrome on my machine:

Service Temporarily Unavailable

> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I have found and will paste the error log below:

```
[Wed Jul 03 12:11:57 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 03 12:12:02 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Orion.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 03 12:12:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 03 12:12:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 03 12:12:02 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 03 12:32:28 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 03 12:32:28 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Orion.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 03 12:32:28 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 03 12:32:28 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 03 12:32:28 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:19 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:19 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:19 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:24 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:24 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:37 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:38 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Orion.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:38 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:38 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:38 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:41 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:41 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:41 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:43 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:04:43 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:06:31 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:06:31 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:06:32 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:09:08 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:09:08 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:09:08 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:10:08 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:10:08 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:10:08 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:21:17 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:21:17 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:21:18 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:35:20 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:35:20 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:35:21 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:35:21 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:36:32 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:36:32 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:36:32 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:37:01 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:37:02 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:19 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:20 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Orion.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:20 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:20 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:20 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:24 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:24 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:25 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:40:25 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:44:45 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:44:45 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:44:46 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:50:15 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 13:50:15 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:50:16 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:50:22 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 13:50:23 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:08:34 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 14:08:34 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:08:35 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:08:35 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:26:37 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 14:26:37 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:26:40 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:26:40 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:29:51 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 14:29:51 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:29:52 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:31:19 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 14:31:19 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:31:19 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:32:50 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 14:32:50 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:32:50 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:33:06 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:33:06 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:33:38 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:33:39 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:34:49 2013] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [fe80::1]:20559 (localhost) failed
[Wed Jul 03 14:34:49 2013] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:34:50 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:34:52 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:34:54 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 03 14:34:55 2013] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
```

Not exactly sure what to do with this and I would really like to get up and running.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Apache is trying to connect to an upstream proxy at `fe80::1` port 20559, but there is no service running at that address/port. Since no service is running, Apache gets `Connection refused` and returns a 503 error.

To resolve the issue, either start the service, or use the correct IP address/port number, as applicable. (It's unlikely that `fe80::1` is the correct address.)

Comment: MACs have `fe80::1%lo0 localhost` as an entry in their hosts file so it could be a valid address.

Comment: He'd have to put the `%lo0` on the end, then. It seems to be missing. Though I would consider that broken; `localhost` is `::1` and `::1` is `localhost`...

Comment: Ok so I have had a look at my hosts file as Iain has said and this is what is showing: `127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost` I don't really know what to do here to resolve the issue so I would really like some help.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong file. It's your Apache configuration you need to be looking at.

Comment: Ok Michael I have had a look at my config file and there doesn't seem to be anything in there too sinister that I can figure out. So what I have done is uploaded a copy of it into a Gist on GitHub. I would really appreciate it if you would have a look for me and see if you think there is anything amiss. https://gist.github.com/johnend/5966532